# dropzone multifile upload & send json data after completing one upload

Tags: dropzone.js

i am using `Dropzone`, for uploading my files. so here i can send multiple files in multiple requests to the server.

What i want is to send some `json` data from server back to `JS` after saving the entry into my database.

### Code

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var md = new Dropzone(".mydropzone", {
    url: "/upload/",
    maxFilesize: "5",
    addRemoveLinks: true
});

md.on("complete", function (file, response) {
    alert(response)
    if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
        alert('awais');
    }

    md.removeFile(file);
});
```